# jquery - smooth modify css clip-path

Tags: jquery, css, mousemove, clip-path

I have a element with `css clip-path.` Depending on the cursor position (Xcord) `jquery` modify `clip-path` points.

My code works great, but I want to slow down (slow and smooth) this "animation" even if the cursor moves quickly.

how can I achieve that?
thx for help

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
  var clip = $(".element");
  //x coordinates
  var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
  //calculate %
  xPercent = xCord / $(document).width() * 100;
  var left = 90 + 10 * (xPercent / 100);
  var right = 100 - 10 * (xPercent / 100);
     
  $(".element").css('clip-path', 'polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% ' + left + '%, 0% ' + right + '%)');
});
```

```css
.element {
background:red;
width:500px;
height:150px;
clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a transition on the CSS code

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos) {
  var clip = $(".element");
  //x coordinates
  var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
  //calculate %
  xPercent = xCord / $(document).width() * 100;
  var left = 90 + 10 * (xPercent / 100);
  var right = 100 - 10 * (xPercent / 100);

  $(".element").css('clip-path', 'polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% ' + left + '%, 0% ' + right + '%)');
});
```

```css
.element {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 90%);
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```